# Preventing repetitive Select Case

Tags: .net, vb.net

In the following code I have two Select Cases, which are nearly identical, and moreover all of the cases are nearly identical. Since they are using overloaded constructors with different parameters, I cant figure out a way to put them into a single function. Is there any way to do this at all (ideally without using generics or reflection and with option strict on?)

```
Sub Main() 'for testing, this currently converts csv to csv
    inputPath = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(1)
    inputType = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(2).ToUpper
    outputPath = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(3)
    outputType = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(4).ToUpper

    'Grab Input
    Select Case inputType
        Case "CSV"
            inputSpreadSheet = New CSV(inputPath)
        Case "XLS"
            inputSpreadSheet = New XLS(inputPath)
        Case "XLSX"
            Throw New NotImplementedException()
        Case "PIPE"
            Throw New NotImplementedException()
        Case Else
            Throw New Exception(inputType & " Is not a valid input type.")
    End Select

    'Convert Input to Intermediate Format
    intermediateSpreadSheet = inputSpreadSheet.ToIntermediate()

    'Convert Intermediate to output Format
    Select Case outputType
        Case "CSV"
            outputSpreadSheet = New CSV(intermediateSpreadSheet)
        Case "XLS"
            outputSpreadSheet = New XLS(intermediateSpreadSheet)
        Case "XLSX"
            Throw New NotImplementedException()
        Case "PIPE"
            Throw New NotImplementedException()
        Case Else
            Throw New Exception(outputType & " Is not a valid output type.")
    End Select

    'Generate output file
    outputSpreadSheet.Export(outputPath)
End Sub
```

Since the parameters for the constructors are of different types in each select block, I know of no way to combine them.

Comment: its not really repetitive, it is testing 2 different things and creating different things as a result

Answer (score 1):

There's not really a way to condense that because it's testing different things and shaping different outputs. For "prettier" code, just create a `GetOutputSpreadSheet(outputType)` and `GetInputSpreadSheet(inputType)` method so you don't have to look at them anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If both blocks take as input a path (assuming it's String) and a type for output sheet and then return some object say of type SpreadSheet, then you could have a function like the following:

```
Public Static Function CreateSpreadSheet(ByVal path As String, ByVal type As String) As SpreadSheet
  Select Case type
    Case "CSV"
        Return New CSV(path)
    Case "XLS"
        Return New XLS(path)
    Case "XLSX"
        Return NotImplementedException()
    Case "PIPE"
        Return NotImplementedException()
    Case Else
        Throw New Exception(type & " is not a valid output type")
  End Select
End Function
```

and then use like this:

```
Sub Main() 'for testing, this currently converts csv to csv
  inputPath = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(1)
  inputType = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(2).ToUpper
  outputPath = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(3)
  outputType = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(4).ToUpper

  'Grab Input
  inputSpreadSheeet = CreateSpreadSheet(inputPath, inputType);

  'Convert Input to Intermediate Format
  intermediateSpreadSheet = inputSpreadSheet.ToIntermediate();

  'Convert Intermediate to output Format
  outputSpreadSheet = CreateSpreadSheet(intermediateSpreadSheet.GetPath(), outputType);

  'Generate output file
  outputSpreadSheet.Export(outputPath)
End Sub
```

This assumes that there is some class called SpreadSheet that is a common ancestor of CSV, XLS, etc.

Also, that SpreadSheet class has a GetPath method to return its path, so that we can ask for the intermediate spreadsheet's file location. That is, supposing ToIntermediate saves it to disk in some intermediate format that New CSV etc. understand to load. In your code the same constructors seemed to accept an object apart from a path and that was the reason you couldn't "merge" the two select statements, since in the 1st one you constructed object with path parameter and at 2nd one with a SpreadSheet object parameter.

If you don't want to save to file the temp spreadsheet, then obviously you can't merge the two select statements (you need to have common input and output types to those code blocks to refactor them as a single reusable function)